# Munin - how to return unknown value from plugin

Tags: plugins, ntp, munin

I want my munin plugin to report unknown values if the value can't be reported. What do I have to return?

- "nan"
- "-nan"
- nothing at all, just skip returning a value
- "unknown"
- ...?

Nothing works for me.

Background: ntp_offset plugin fails if ntp is not running at all. I want to return unknown value and send an alert message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the correct value to return is "U".

This is briefly mentioned without explanation in the documentation:

https://munin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/plugin.html#fieldname-value

Comment: Great, I love munin, but the documentation is rather bad organized.